# how to sort an array based on a different array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

i have this array

```
array(
    'pc' => array('count'=>3),
    'xbox' => array('count'=>3),
    'wii' => array('count'=>3),
    '3ds' => array('count'=>3),
    'other' => array('count'=>3),
)
```

and i want to order it like

```
array(
    'wii' => array('count'=>3),
    'xbox' => array('count'=>3),
    'other' => array('count'=>3),
    '3ds' => array('count'=>3),
    'pc' => array('count'=>3),
)
```

im thinking that i need to have another array to sort it by??

the keys might not be the same, so i think an `isset()` is in order at one point

edit: the criteria is the second array keys

any ideas?

Comment: What is the criteria for sorting? I don't see one.

Comment: Seems quite random to me @JohnConde

Comment: edit: the criteria is the second array keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to define a custom sorting algorithm. You can do that by using PHP's [`uksort()`](http://www.php.net/uksort) function. (The difference to the very similar [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/usort) function being that it compares the array's keys instead of its values.)

It could look somewhat like this (requires PHP >= 5.3 because of the anonymous functions I use in it):

```
<?php
$input = array(
    'pc' => array('count'=>3),
    'xbox' => array('count'=>3),
    'wii' => array('count'=>3),
    '3ds' => array('count'=>3),
    'other' => array('count'=>3),
);
$keyOrder = array('wii', 'xbox', 'other', '3ds', 'pc');

uksort($input, function($a, $b) use ($keyOrder) {
    // Because of the "use" construct, $keyOrder will be available within
    // this function.
    // $a and $b will be two keys that have to be compared against each other.

    // First, get the positions of both keys in the $keyOrder array.
    $positionA = array_search($a, $keyOrder);
    $positionB = array_search($b, $keyOrder);

    // array_search() returns false if the key has not been found. As a
    // fallback value, we will use count($keyOrder) -- so missing keys will
    // always rank last. Set them to 0 if you want those to be first.
    if ($positionA === false) {
        $positionA = count($keyOrder);
    }
    if ($positionB === false) {
        $positionB = count($keyOrder);
    }

    // To quote the PHP docs:
    // "The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
    //  greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
    //  respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second."
    return $positionA - $positionB;
});

print_r($input);
```